# Is "to attribute a property" equal to "to give a property"?

Tags: word-choice, synonyms

I'm wondering if I can use both. For instance in: "We can give/attribute a property of an eraser to a pencil."

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I don't see how we could "give" a property of something to something, unless we were a designer or manufacturer. But we can certainly attribute properties to things - though that of an eraser to a pencil seems unlikely. I have never had a pencil which was capable of erasing. If you are talking about a pencil with an eraser at the unsharpened end, then the maker could "give" it that property. But to attribute something to something you need to claim that the thing attributed exists - e.g. one could attribute an acidic property to lemon juice.

Comment: Yeah, I meant it from a standpoint of a designer/manufacturer. Thanks for your thoughts! BTW, nice example in the end!